# PostgreSQL function returning different number of rows

Tags: postgresql

Version PostgreSQL 13.8

Function returns data other than a direct query.

function query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM public.function1(10, '2023-04-17', '180 min')
```

function:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.function1(
    argument1 bigint,
    argument2 date,
    argument3 interval)
    RETURNS TABLE(column1 double precision, column2 text) 
    LANGUAGE 'sql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE PARALLEL UNSAFE
    ROWS 1000

AS $BODY$
WITH     "t_temp" AS (
              SELECT "table"."column1",
                   "table"."column2" + $3 AS "column2",
                   "table"."column3" AS "CurrentColumn3",
                   LAG("table"."column3") OVER (ORDER BY "table"."column2") AS "PreviousColumn3",
                   LEAD("table"."column3") OVER (ORDER BY "table"."column2") AS "NextColumn3"
              FROM "table"
              WHERE "table"."column4" = $1 AND
                  TO_DATE(cast("table"."column2" + $3 as TEXT), 'YYYY-MM-DD') = $2 AND
                  "table"."column3" IS NOT NULL
              ORDER BY "table"."column2"
          )
SELECT   EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM "t_temp"."column2") AS "column2",
         encode("t_temp"."CurrentColumn3", 'hex'::text) AS "column3"
FROM     "t_temp"
WHERE    "t_temp"."CurrentColumn3" <> "t_temp"."PreviousColumn3" OR
         "t_temp"."PreviousColumn3" IS NULL OR
           "t_temp"."NextColumn3" IS NULL
GROUP BY "column2", "column3"
ORDER BY "column2";
$BODY$;
```

direct query:

```sql
WITH     "t_temp" AS (
              SELECT "table"."column1",
                   "table"."column2" + '180 min' AS "column2",
                   "table"."column3" AS "CurrentColumn3",
                   LAG("table"."column3") OVER (ORDER BY "table"."column2") AS "PreviousColumn3",
                   LEAD("table"."column3") OVER (ORDER BY "table"."column2") AS "NextColumn3"
              FROM "table"
              WHERE "table"."column4" = 10 AND
                  TO_DATE(cast("table"."column2" + '180 min' as TEXT), 'YYYY-MM-DD') = '2023-04-17' AND
                  "table"."column3" IS NOT NULL
              ORDER BY "table"."column2"
          )
SELECT   EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM "t_temp"."column2") AS "column2",
         encode("t_temp"."CurrentColumn3", 'hex'::text) AS "column3"
FROM     "t_temp"
WHERE    "t_temp"."CurrentColumn3" <> "t_temp"."PreviousColumn3" OR
         "t_temp"."PreviousColumn3" IS NULL OR
           "t_temp"."NextColumn3" IS NULL
GROUP BY "column2", "column3"
ORDER BY "column2";
```

table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public."table"
(
    column1 bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('table_column1_seq'::regclass),
    column2 bytea,
    column3 timestamp(0) without time zone NOT NULL,
    column4 bigint NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT column1_pkey PRIMARY KEY (column1),
    CONSTRAINT table_column4_foreign FOREIGN KEY (column4)
        REFERENCES public.table2 (column1) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

Direct query always returns the same number of rows(9), but function query always returns a different number of rows(9-13). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could be many things: 1) you query a different database 2) your `search_path` is set differently and you query tables in different schemas 3) you run the queries in different user contexts, and row level security is enabled 4) you see different versions of the data, because one query is run in a long running `REPEATABLE READ` transaction. There could be more reasons. Go and debug the problem by following an individual result row back to where it comes from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be facing issue with "VOLATILE" keyword here. As per the documentation [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html#:%7E:text=VOLATILE%20indicates%20that%20the%20function,%2C%20currval()%20%2C%20timeofday()%20.), this keyword specifies that the result of function may change within query.

Try modifying your function definition to use "STABLE" instead of
"VOLATILE".